# How to recover data from 2tb wd external harddrive which is showing as 'Not Initialized' in disk mangement?

Tags: external-hard-drive

It is my brother's hard drive & it has very important data.
It is a 2tb wd my passport ultra external hard disk which was used as ntfs with only one partition.

My brother told me that he deleted some data from the drive by mistake and was recovering the data from the drive but all the windows recovery programs he used just hung up after few minutes (which is also a sign of bad sectors). Then he blundered by formatting the drive.

Now the current situation is that the drive is not showing in the windows explorer and when I open the disk management the popup came up for initializing the disk either as MBR or GPT. When I try to initialize the disk, it gives me this error:- "The request failed due to a fatal device hardware error".

I have tried cloning the drive with clonezilla, tried booting the drive with parted magic, Hire n boot and system rescue CD but neither of them recognised the drive and also rejected to boot with the drive attached.

Please tell me if there is any hope left for drive like partition recovery or cloning the drive via some tools.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless it's worth money to hire a professional recovery service, I'd say it's gone. As it was only backup, implying the original data is still fine, it would be simpler to just buy a new drive.

Answer (score 1):

Have changed the USB cable? Those can cause problems way more often that you expect. Especially when it comes to portable HDDs, because they are getting the power trough the USB cable.  Also make sure you connect it directly to a USB 3.0 port on the back of the PC. Try those and run the data recovery software again. Although, to be honest the chances are very slim having in mind that the HDD was initialized.  The best chance of success you'll get with using professional data recovery services.  This is the list of the WD Data Recovery Partners http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=MTROyM .